# Authentication times out on login (passportJS) and I'm desperate

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, authentication, passport.js

I'm very new to Passport & Node, I've been trying to solve an issue for several days without being able to find a solution that already exists on SO or the internet. I'm getting no errors or anything on login attempt, nothing in chrome dev, nothing in gitbash. Only problem is page never redirects, never seems to get through the passport.authenticate function inside my auth controller (/dologin). When I attempt a login, the browser never stops loading (ex. the circle keeps spinning for chrome), I have no problems with internet or anything of that nature, I only have this problem when implementing the login feature. One thing that I suspect might be an issue is that I do not have my localstrategy/serialization/deserialization in the right spot but I have tried it in app.js as well so at this point I'm really just too confused.

app.js - I tried including the initialize > session > localstrategy > serialize > deserialize in here, but it also didn't work so I just left initialize and session

```
// // Init passport authentication
app.use(passport.initialize());
// persistent login sessions
app.use(passport.session());
```

index.js

```
// route for login action
router.post('/dologin', auth.doLogin);
```

authController.js

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function (username, password, done) {
        User.getUserByUsername(username, function (err, user) {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown User' });
            }

            User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function (err, isMatch) {
                if (err) throw err;
                if (isMatch) {
                    return done(null, user);
                } else {
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password' });
                }
            });
        });
    }));

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    User.getUserById(id, function (err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

userController.doLogin = function(req, res) {
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/', failureRedirect: '/doLogin', failureFlash: true }),
    function (req, res) {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
};
```

users.js (model) - includes getUserByUsername, comparePassword, getUserbyId

```
module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback){
  var query = {username: username};
  User.findOne(query, callback);
}

module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback){
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch){
    if (err) throw err;
    callback(null, isMatch);
  });
}

module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
  User.findById(id, callback);
}
```